# Как восстановить удалённый репозиторий на github

Tags: github

Удалил свой репозиторй на github, после чего удалил и локальные файлы (не спрашивайте почему и как, так получилось), теперь необходимо восстановить удалённый репозиторий на github, это возможно?

Comment: Наверное надо в поддержку гитхаба обратиться. У них наверняка некоторое время хранятся бэкапы

Comment: Гитхаб не делает бэкапы репозиториев. Восстановить можно только имея локальный репозиторий выполнив `git push origin master`.

Comment: посмотри в корзине,мб там лежат ))

Comment: В поддержку гитхаба обратиться стоит, но особых надежд я бы на вашем месте не питал.

Comment: Еще вариант, если не прокатит с поддержкой гитхаба: банальное восстановление данных на харде. RStudio, HDD Recovery Pro, Recuva и прочие многочисленные программы. Правда может быть в некоторых местах покоцано, но в целом можно хоть что-то восстановить будет

Comment: Маловероятное восстановление, если нет ни локального ни удаленного экземпляра репо. И сам GitHub также не поможет (служба поддержки). Только как указали выше, попробовать восстановить хард.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению *github* не восстанавливает удаленные репозитории.

Хорошей идеей стало попытаться восстановить удаленные файлы с жесткого диска, но это уже выходит за рамки данной темы.

Answer (score 1):

Люди, я чуть не поседел когда прочитал ваш ответ который первой ссылкой по такому запросу выходит

Можно восстановить свой репозиторий через настройки (если удален меньше 90 дней):
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/restoring-a-deleted-repository
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ нужно дополнить. Не каждый репозиторий можно восстановить и не все будет восстановлено.

Comment: + нельзя восстановить удаленные форки и форкнутые репозитории: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kPJT.png